# How to make stripped box shadow using HTML & CSS only?

Tags: html, css

So, I want to make a navbar button with a stripped box shadow while hovered. Like this :

[Image link](https://i.ibb.co/LCwshsq/fn-FUb-Apk4-C.gif)

I've tried to make it using CSS box-shadow and linear gradient. But it doesn't work.

And here is my current HTML & CSS code:

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul{
  height: 10vh;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul a{
    margin: auto;
}

ul li{
  margin: auto;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px yellow;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Nav 1</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

So, can I make a stripped box shadow like that using HTML & CSS only?

If it's not possible using HTML & CSS only, then how to make it? What technologies/tools I must use to make a stripped shadow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-image` can help you here:

```css
.box {
  --b:10; /* control the border */
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width:0 calc(var(--b)*1px) calc(var(--b)*1px) 0;
  background:red padding-box;
  border-image:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,#0000 0 4px,blue 0 8px) var(--b);
  /* cut the corners with clip-path*/
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,calc(100% - calc(var(--b)*1px)) 0,calc(100% - calc(var(--b)*1px)) calc(var(--b)*1px),100% calc(var(--b)*1px),100% 100%,calc(var(--b)*1px) 100%,calc(var(--b)*1px) calc(100% - calc(var(--b)*1px)),0 calc(100% - calc(var(--b)*1px)))
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text here</div>

<div class="box" style="--b:5"> some text here</div>
<div class="box" style="--b:15"> some text here</div>
```